# socket auth failing when trying to connect

Tags: node.js, socket.io

it is always showing disconnect.

i tried all possibilities. sometime it authenticates.

any help is deeply appreciated.

am using
https://github.com/facundoolano/socketio-auth

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function(){
  socket.emit('authentication', {username: "John", password: "secret"});
  socket.on('authenticated', function() {
    // use the socket as usual
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the timeout option in socket io auth

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

require('socketio-auth')(io, {
  authenticate: authenticate, 
  postAuthenticate: postAuthenticate,
  timeout: 1000
});
```

Try changing the timeout value, until it is success.

Answer (score 0):

Also add event handlers to capture any errors, or unauth messages.

```
socket.on('unauthorized', function(err){
  console.log("There was an error with the authentication:", err.message); 
});

socket.on('error', function(err){
  console.log("There was an error ", err); 
});
```